# A promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it

Tags: truffle, javascript

Hey I'm new to javascript promises. I am getting several errors stating a promise is created but not returned. How do you return from a promise?

Comment: A minimum of example code and error messages are needed in the order to receive any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a purely Javascript thing, the interpreter does not like it when you create a Promise in a scope, and do not return it out of it.

```
function standardOne() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  //^^ See this return? That's what you need to do.
        // do something
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I need to do some studying on promises and callbacks